# AWS EC2 restricted from resizing from t2.micro to t2.small

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have been currently running my application fine on a t2.micro instance.  Recently, I have made some changes that require more cpu usage and because of the nature of t2.micro instances, AWS starts to throttle my instance by putting the cpu at 99% usage after a few hours of running between 5% and 20% which eventually breaks my application, but sometimes will return back to 5% cpu for no reason.  I have read on the forums of many others having the same issue with a micro instance, but when I try to go to small, the console says that I am restricted to zero instances of t2.small and I have to contact support to increase the limit!  It has been several days since I contacted support, but still no action has been taken.  How does everyone else deal with this kind of restriction?  It's like they are telling me I cannot afford to pay a nickel per hour when I have been paying a penny an hour just fine.  I am currently looking at moving the whole application off of AWS because of this.

Comment: To whoever just downvoted this for lack of research, there is no case that I can find of anyone else having this issue and amazon support has not been any help.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer my own question in case anyone else runs into this.  Amazon has removed the restriction, and I am now able to create small instances.  There is a page in the console that shows you what your limits are, and I suggest anyone starting out to go ahead and get your limit increased if you are not even allowed to make a small instance before you run into issues.